# Javascript smooth scroll iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari

i use this code,
to scroll overflow div (hidden) in ipad , and works expect its not smooth , is there any way i can make it smooth scroll ?

```
function initMobileScroll(ele) {
var mobileScrollArea = document.getElementById(ele);

mobileScrollArea.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){
    touchstart (event);
});

mobileScrollArea.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event){
    touchmove (event);
});

// let’s set the starting point when someone first touches
function touchstart (e) {
    startY = e.touches[0].pageY;
    startX = e.touches[0].pageX;
}

// calls repeatedly while the user’s finger is moving
function touchmove(e) {
    var touches = e.touches[0];

    // override the touch event’s normal functionality
            e.preventDefault();

    // y-axis
    var touchMovedY = startY - touches.pageY;
    startY = touches.pageY; // reset startY for the next call
    mobileScrollArea.scrollTop = mobileScrollArea.scrollTop + touchMovedY;

    // x-axis
    var touchMovedX = startX - touches.pageX;
    startX = touches.pageX; // reset startX for the next call
    mobileScrollArea.scrollLeft = mobileScrollArea.scrollLeft + touchMovedX;
}   

}
```

code source : http://www.flexmls.com/developers/2011/04/13/ipad-and-single-finger-scrolling-in-flexmls/

Answer (score 6):

add this to your css:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

### Compatibility

- **Safari:** iOS 5
- **Android Browser:** 3.0
- **Blackberry Browser:** 6
- **Chrome for Mobile**
- **Firefox Mobile**
- **IE Mobile:** 9
- **Opera Mobile**

> example: [JSfiddle](http://goo.gl/PTfMFE)
>
> reference: [barrow.io - Overflow scrolling](https://goo.gl/wsx7eW)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Answer (score 1):

Looks similar to what I was trying to do.. Good luck

```
if (evt.type == "touchstart")
{
    tsStartY = evt.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY;
}
if (evt.type == "touchend")
{
    var te = evt.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY;
    var delta = tsStartY - te;

    if (tsStartY > te) {
        // going down
        this.transY += delta;

        if (this.transY > this.minY)
        {
            this.transY = this.minY;
        }

    }
    if (tsStartY < te)
    {
        // going up
        this.transY -= -delta;
        if (this.transY < this.maxY) {
            this.transY = this.maxY;
        }
    }


}
```